# MySQL FULL JOIN with COUNTs and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
| id | col1     | col2     | col3  | valid |
| 1  | apple    |          |       | 1     |
| 2  | lemon    | apple    |       | 1     |
| 3  | lemon    | pear     |       | 1     |
| 4  | carrot   | apple    |       | 1     |
| 5  | potatoes | tomatoes | apple | 1     |
| 6  | banana   |          |       | 0     |
| 6  | banana   |          |       | 1     |
```

I need to create a MySQL query, that returns counts for each entry in each column. Ideally something like:

```
| apple    | 1    | 2    | 1
| carrot   | 1    | null | null
| lemon    | 2    | null | null
| pear     | null | 1    | null
| potatoes | 1    | null | null
| tomatoes | null | 1    | null
| banana   | 1    | null | null
```

The format **could be different**, my result should show how many times appear some value in some column.

It should be done only with one query, I can't use any other languages, any other subresults etc...., just:

```
    (one query)
`input` -> `output`.
```

My best try is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM      (SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) FROM sometable WHERE valid = 1 GROUP BY col1) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT col2, COUNT(col2) FROM sometable WHERE valid = 1 GROUP BY col2) t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT col3, COUNT(col3) FROM sometable WHERE valid = 1 GROUP BY col3) t3
    ON t1.col1 = t3.col3
```

But with `LEFT JOIN` I loose some of my rows (with value only in 2nd or 3rd col), I tried several different "join-s", with any success in MySQL

**EDIT:** The values are dynamic, I don't know the exact unique possibilities before

Comment: You are looking for `pivoting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, just have 1 more subquery, where you list all possible values from the 3 columns using `union distinct` and you need subqueries to get counts by each cols separately:

```
select f.fruits, m1.fruit_count1, m2.fruit_count2, m3.fruit_count3
from
    (select distinct col1 as fruits from mytable
      union
     select distinct col2 from mytable 
      union
     select distinct col3 from mytable) f
left join
    (select col1, count(col1) as fruit_count1 from mytable where valid=1 group by  col1) m1 on f.fruits=m1.col1
left join
    (select col2, count(col2) as fruit_count2 from mytable where valid=1 group by  col2) m2 on f.fruits=m2.col2
left join
    (select col3, count(col3) as fruit_count3 from mytable where valid=1 group by  col3) m3 on f.fruits=m3.col3;
```

Comment: Thanks for ideas, but it is not working, on sample values from my question I got `apple 2 2 2`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but since it basicly says that my solution does not work without providing any hints of how you exactly tried to implement the query

Comment: I use exactly the same as you wrote, only I change `mytable` to `sometable` and in the last row I add `s` so it is `fruits`

Comment: Check out the updated answer. Revised the code to get the counts in separate subqueries.

Comment: I have only a little slower reaction, your code is awesome! You really helped me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
select
      item,
      sum( case when whichCol = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as FoundCol1,
      sum( case when whichCol = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as FoundCol2,
      sum( case when whichCol = 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as FoundCol3
   from
      ( select col1 as item, 1 as whichCol 
           from YourTable 
           where valid = 1
        union all
        select col2 as item, 2 as whichCol 
           from YourTable 
           where valid = 1
        union all
        select col3 as item, 3 as whichCol 
           from YourTable 
           where valid = 1) allRows
   group by
      item
```

You need sum of the case and identifier which column the item originated from respectively.

An even more efficient approach would pre-aggregate the counts per column especially if you are dealing with large data set

```
select
      item,
      sum( case when whichCol = 1 then TotRecs else 0 end ) as FoundCol1,
      sum( case when whichCol = 2 then TotRecs else 0 end ) as FoundCol2,
      sum( case when whichCol = 3 then TotRecs else 0 end ) as FoundCol3
   from
      ( select col1 as item, max(1) as whichCol, count(*) as TotRecs
           from YourTable 
           group by col1
        union all
        select col2 as item, max(2) as whichCol, count(*) as TotRecs
           from YourTable 
           group by col2
        union all
        select col3 as item, max(3) as whichCol, count(*) as TotRecs
           from YourTable 
           group by col3 ) allRows
   group by
      item
```